# For a table A, is it possible to redundantly store some of the columns of its unique type table AType?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `room`

```sql
create table room(
  id int NOT_NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(30),
  person_num int comment 'the person number of this room',
  room_type char(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

table `room` has a column named `room_type`, it is a foreign key constraint on the table `room` and the table `room_type`

```sql
create table room_type(
  id char(1) NOT_NULL,
  person_max tinyint comment 'the max person number of this type room',
  cost decimal(9,3) comment 'room cost per year',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The table `room_type` has few records, at least, it will not exceed the length of the alphabet.

However, there are many records in the table `room`. In the case of assuming that the records of room exceed 500,000,

is it necessary to redundant `person_max` of table `room_type` to table `room` to reduce the time consumed by connecting tables

Comment: What is logical relation between `room.person_num` and `room_type.person_max`?

Comment: A room has two columns person_num and person_max,
`person_num` means the current number of occupants in this room,
`person_max` is the maximum number of people allowed in this room.
                                                                                                                                                   
The relationship between person_num and person_max is that person_num must be less than or equal to person_max,
person_max is determined by room_type, and the relationship between room_type ,and room is one-to-many, and person_num is the column of room

Comment: @Akina A more realistic example would be:
An apartment has four types of rooms A,B,C,D.
A is a room for 1 person, B is a room for 2 people, C is for 4, D is for 6.
Then rooms 101-199 on the 1st floor have their own different types.
For example, 101-120 is type A,
121-140 is type B,
141-170 is C,
171-199 is D,
Although both 121 and 130 are type B, there is no relationship between the number of people already in rooms 121 and 130

Comment: *`person_num` means the current number of occupants in this room* - overdefined data? This value can be counted by guests table, is it?

Comment: @Akina Yes, each guest has its own room number, so the number of people in each room can be calculated by querying the guest table. But the data of the guest table is larger than the data volume of the room table (if the room table has at least 500,000 records, then the guest table may be 3-6 times as much), so for convenience, I added `person_num` to the room table Columns to easily see the number of people in each room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General rules, and how they apply to your situation.

- Redundant data is a no-no in schema design.  (So not repeat `person_max` in `room`.)
- The cost of a `JOIN` is usually small enough so that you do not need to worry about the performance.  Joins should have a suitable index to make the action efficient.  (You have `PRIMARY KEY(id)` for `room_type`, so that is good.)
- Avoid "premature optimization".  (That is, don't worry about the speed of `JOIN` until you have evidence that there is a problem.)